# Custom taxonomy template list not working (404)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, 404-error

I have created a custom post type 'item':

```
function mywp_add_item_post() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Items',
        'singular_name' => 'Item',
        'add_new' => 'Add New Item',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Item',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
        'new_item' => 'New Item',
        'all_items' => 'All Items',
        'view_item' => 'View Item',
        'search_items' => 'Search Items',
        'not_found' =>  'No Items Found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Items found in Trash', 
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Items',
        'show_in_nav_menus'=>true
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'item'),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-randomize',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'=>true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'author', 'page-attributes'));

    register_post_type( 'item', $args );
  }

add_action( 'init', 'mywp_add_item_post');
```

A custom taxonomy named 'collection' is added:

```
function mywp_add_collection_taxonomy() {
      $labels= array('name' => _x( 'Collections', 'taxonomy general name' ),
      'singular_name' => _x( 'Collection', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
      'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Collections' ),
      'all_items' => __( 'All Collection' ),
      'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Collection' ),
      'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Collection:' ),
      'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Collection' ),
      'update_item' => __( 'Update Collection' ),
      'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Collection' ),
      'new_item_name' => __( 'New Collection Name' ),
      'menu_name' => __( 'Collections' ));

      $rewrite= array('slug' => 'collection');

  $args= array('hierarchical' => true,
      'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'labels'=>$labels,
      'query_var' => true,
      'show_in_rest' => true,
      'rewrite'=>$rewrite);

   register_taxonomy('collection', 'item', $args);
}

function mywp_tax_filters()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('collection', 'item');
}

add_action('init', 'mywp_add_collection_taxonomy', 1);
add_action('init', 'mywp_tax_filters');
```

**Object:** I need a page to view the list of 'collection' that are not empty (like the default categories page)

- A taxonomy template file (*taxonomy-collection.php*) is created
  within the theme directory.
- Permalink structure is flushed.
- I have added some 'collections' assigning 'items' inside them.

**Problem:**
The link '$site_url/collection' shows 404 (not found).

Advance thanks for your thoughts on my problem and your patience to read it all through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A missing template will never result in a 404 error. That's not how templates work. The reason you're getting a 404 is that you're attempting to access a URL that does not exist.

`{Site URL}/{Taxonomy name}/` doesn't exist. There's nothing for WordPress to display at that URL. WordPress templates only ever display *posts*, but this URL doesn't specify which posts to display. You need to specify which collection term to display, and then access posts with that term at `{Site URL}/{Taxonomy name}/{Term slug}`. *All* posts would be accessible at  `{Site URL}/{Post type name}/`, but `{Site URL}/{Taxonomy name}/` will return a 404.

If you want to display a list of terms within a taxonomy, then the only way to do that would be to create a page with a custom template that lists all terms. It's not a native type of template in WordPress.

Comment: Thanks jacob. As there is an option to display the categories, I presumed wordpress can display the list of custom taxonomy names too. The links like {Site URL}/{Taxonomy slug}/{Taxonomy name} is working fine.
I understand the issue and will create a separate page template and code to display the list.
Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: There isn’t an option to display the categories. Unless you just mean the widget? There’s certainly nothing accessible at `{Site URL}/category/`.